# .live() trigger event does not work after changing to .on()

Tags: jquery

I want to delete rows from table dynamiclly for which I was using .live() method and it worked ok.
But now .live method is deprecated so I want to use .on(), but it won't work.

```
    $(".delete").live('click', function(){
        var cresponse = confirm("Confirm that you want to delete a deal.");
        if(cresponse) {
            var cid = $(this).attr('xtarget');
            userRolesUpd(cid, 'Y');
        }
    });
```

I changed to:

```
    $(".delete").on('click', function(){
        var cresponse = confirm("Confirm that you want to delete a deal.");
        if(cresponse) {
            var cid = $(this).attr('xtarget');
            userRolesUpd(cid, 'Y');
        }
    });
```

It is working only for one row, after I update table rows, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

The [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function is used wrong - see http://api.jquery.com/live/ for the correct equivalencies when updating code.

```
  $(".delete").live('click', function ..)
//   ^-- 'live' selector
```

Is equivalent to

```
  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function ..)
//  ^-- common ancestor    ^-- 'live' selector
```

It there is a more refined parent than "document" is is advisable to use that instead. See the `on` documentation.